# Tensorflow cifar10_input.py

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement cifar10 model in tensorflow.The code for the tutorial is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.10/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10).

The file [cifar10_input.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.10/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py) deals with handling of cifar10 input in binary form.I am not able to comprehend-

1)The function of tf.FixedLengthRecordReader.As much I could understand,It takes binary files and expresses them as a fixed length records.It is highly unclear.An example might help.

2)The variable "value"(Argument of tf.decode_raw).What does it contain and how does tf.decode_raw converts the value in "value" to uint8?Again an example might help.

Long story short,I need an working example to get a feel what these three lines of code are actually doing-

```
reader = tf.FixedLengthRecordReader(record_bytes=record_bytes)
result.key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
record_bytes = tf.decode_raw(value, tf.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brief answer: take a look at the documentation.

- tf.FixedLengthRecordReader
  https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#FixedLengthRecordReader
  reads records from a file, where a "record" is simply a fixed number of bytes. It returns string tensors.
- tf.decode_raw:
  https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#decode_raw
  takes a string tensor and converts it into a uint8 Tensor.

The CIFAR10 example you linked to is a working example. Try building that and playing with it to get a feel for how all these constructs fit together.

Hope that helps!